# TypeError while executing file

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting

So I am trying to run a file but it keeps giving me this message

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

I opened the file and these were the lines that were causing problem

```py
def inputs_string_to_list(inputs_string: str) -> list[str]:
    """
    Convert a string with comma-separated items into a list of strings.
    :param inputs_string: a string with comma-separated items
    :return: list of strings
    """
    return [input_.strip() for input_ in inputs_string.split(",")]
```

does anybody know a fix ?

Comment: What's your python version?

Comment: Presumably you're using Python pre-3.9, so either upgrade or see the older versions in https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/.

Answer (score 2):

Built-in types became generic [since python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collections). Your Python version is less than 3.9.

The error : `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable` refers to `list[str]` where the `list`(an object of type `type`) is subscripted.

If you want to use type hints for lists, use the [`List`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) from `typing` module. It's the generic version of the built-in `list` prior to Python 3.9:

```py
from typing import List


def inputs_string_to_list(inputs_string: str) -> List[str]:
```

Or upgrade your Python.

**note:** [typing.py](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#module-typing) module itself is new in Python 3.5. So if you are running Python less than 3.5 it's not an option anymore. Upgrade your Python or omit the type hints or use other techniques like [Type Comments](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#type-comments).